# matplotlib ploting charts in reverse using scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

When executing the following code I am getting the attached chart (I am using windows 10 with python 3.6 and pycharm community version).
I could not find a way to use `scatter` and to get my 'x' and 'y' ordered from 0 to max value.
I appreciate your advice!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = ['1940','1300','1420','1680','1270','1850','1000','1100','1600','1000','2150','1900','2200','1100','860','1325','1350','1600','950','1250']
Y = ['1116000','860000','818400','1000000','640000','1010000','600000','700000','1100000','570000','860000','1085000','1250000','850000','640000','900000','730000','750000','650000','680000']
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your X and Y contain strings this messes things up with matplotlib.  If you convert your strings to integers: your axis becomes correct.

```
X = ['1940','1300','1420','1680','1270','1850','1000','1100','1600','1000','2150','1900','2200','1100','860','1325','1350','1600','950','1250']
Y = ['1116000','860000','818400','1000000','640000','1010000','600000','700000','1100000','570000','860000','1085000','1250000','850000','640000','900000','730000','750000','650000','680000']
Xs = [int(x) for x in X]
Ys = [int(y) for y in Y]

plt.scatter(Xs,Ys)
plt.show()
```

resulting in this plot:

[image]

edit based on comment:

You can use slicing to indicate what data you want to convert to numbers and what not. In the below code the `[int(x) for x in X[1:]]` part specifies use every item in the list except index 0. By saving the result in another variable the column header is still in the original data.

```
X = ['header','1940','1300','1420','1680','1270','1850','1000','1100','1600','1000','2150','1900','2200','1100','860','1325','1350','1600','950','1250']
Y = ['other header','1116000','860000','818400','1000000','640000','1010000','600000','700000','1100000','570000','860000','1085000','1250000','850000','640000','900000','730000','750000','650000','680000']
Xs = [int(x) for x in X[1:]]
Ys = [int(y) for y in Y[1:]]

plt.scatter(Xs,Ys)
# bonus use the header as label
plt.xlabel(X[0])
plt.ylabel(Y[0])
plt.show()
```

This code results in this graph:

[image]

Alternatively you could not use an intermediate variable like so:

```
plt.scatter([int(x) for x in X[1:]],[int(y) for y in Y[1:]])
# bonus use the header as label
plt.xlabel(X[0])
plt.ylabel(Y[0])
plt.show()
```

What would result in the same graph as directly above without the need of making intermediate variables.

Comment: thanks. I will make it harder now. the code above was a shortcut so I will not need to load any xlsx file which I import to the dataframe. When I imported as suggested above, it does work but not on imported xlsx data as the data has headers (string) and I am using the headers for cutting/slicing etc. so i can not drop them. Any idea how to set column an integer except to the first raw?